# Get specific info from LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to find a way to receive specific information from LinkedIn to display it on a website.
Exactly, I'd like to be able to get the text and the url of the embed content. Also, get the number of likes and comments that the post has received.
Has anybody done something similar before that could give me some advice?
I've been reading about the LinkedIn API but I only see info about integrating LinkedIn on your web for sharing content on LinkedIn. And what I want is the other way, getting the content from LinkedIn.
Any info would be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: To retrieve information about your company page, you can apply to the LinkedIn Marketing Developer Program for Community Management API access: https://www.linkedin.com/developers/products

Comment: Thanks for the info. I see that what I need is the "social actions" API. And to be able to use it I have to apply for the Marketing Developer Program. Unfortunately if somebody as me is trying to get this working quick, I'm afraid to tell that LinkedIn can take up to 30 days to approve your application.